# Pandas loc indexing with inplace fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53788758/9209546) I came across a behaviour I do not understand.

I am trying to `fillna` specific columns `val2` and `val3` for rows which include the first instance of each value in `id`. For some reason an `inplace` solution with `fillna` doesn't appear to work, and I don't understand why.

Let's assume this input dataframe:

```
    id  val1  val2  val3       date
0  102     9   NaN   4.0 2002-01-01
1  102     2   3.0   NaN 2002-03-03
2  103     4   NaN   NaN 2003-04-04
3  103     7   4.0   5.0 2003-08-09
4  103     6   5.0   1.0 2005-02-03
```

Desired output, with a fill value of `-1`:

```
    id  val1  val2  val3       date
0  102     9  -1.0   4.0 2002-01-01
1  102     2   3.0   NaN 2002-03-03
2  103     4  -1.0  -1.0 2003-04-04
3  103     7   4.0   5.0 2003-08-09
4  103     6   5.0   1.0 2005-02-03
```

Below is a solution that works and the `inplace` variant that does not work:

```
mask = ~df['id'].duplicated()
val_cols = ['val2', 'val3']

df.loc[mask, val_cols] = df.loc[mask, val_cols].fillna(-1)  # WORKS
df.loc[mask, val_cols].fillna(-1, inplace=True)             # DOES NOT WORK
```

I am using Python 3.6.5, Pandas 0.23.0, NumPy 1.14.3.

Possibly this is intended behaviour, but I haven't been able to find a duplicate. As far as I can see, there's no chained indexing involved.

Comment: Check this man https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14858

Comment: @W-B, Thank you. I find it confusing that `SettingwithCopyWarning` comes up so many times when it's not relevant. But here, when it is relevant, there's nothing.

Comment: As such, I also think we need to point to some documentation to know that `loc` always gives a copy. Maybe I missed something in the docs?

Comment: @jpp `loc` does not always give a copy sometimes it does return a view: `df.loc[:, 'val2'].fillna(-1, inplace=True)` `df.loc[:, column]` may return a view but not always: if it contains multiple columns as in `df.loc[:, df.columns[2:4]]`. It seems that if `loc` contains multiple columns then it returns a copy where one column returns a view

Comment: See [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367442/pandas-dataframe-view-vs-copy-how-do-i-tell) here along with the comments. `loc` with `__setitem__` works on the view. `loc` with `__getitem__` returns a copy most of the time.

Comment: @ayhan, Thank you. Basically there are rules of thumbs, but whether or not you have a copy or a view is an implementation detail. I'm going to close this as a duplicate. But if anyone wants to construct a better answer feel free to reopen.