# Why does one use of iloc() give a SettingWithCopyWarning, but the other doesn't?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

Inside a method from a class i use this statement:

```
self.__datacontainer.iloc[-1]['c'] = value
```

Doing this i get a 
"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Now i tried to reproduce this error and write the following simple code:

```
import pandas, numpy
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randn(5,3),columns=list('ABC'))
df.iloc[-1]['C'] = 3
```

There i get no error. Why do i get an error in the first statement and not in the second?

Comment: Looks like `self.__datacontainer` is a slice of another dataframe. You need to make a copy explicitly. For example, with `df.copy()`

Comment: this doesnt help i tried :
    `df = self.__datacontainer.copy()`
    `df.iloc[-1]['c'] = value`
and get the same warning

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Chain indexing**

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) and a couple of other answers on this site ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)) suggest, chain indexing is considered bad practice and should be avoided.

Since there doesn't seem to be a graceful way of making assignments using *integer position based indexing* (i.e. `.iloc`) without violating the chain indexing rule (as of pandas `v0.23.4`), it is advised to instead use *label based indexing* (i.e. `.loc`) for assignment purposes whenever possible.

However, if you absolutely need to access data by row number you can

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('c')] = 42
```

or

```
df.iloc[[-1, 1], df.columns.get_indexer(['a', 'c'])] = 42
```

---

**Pandas behaving oddly**

From my understanding you're absolutely right to expect the warning when trying to reproduce the error artificially.

What I've found so far is that it depends on how a dataframe is constructed

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [3, 2, 1]})
df.iloc[-1]['c'] = 42 # no warning
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'c': ['t', 'u', 'v']})
df.iloc[-1]['c'] = 'f' # no warning
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'c': [3, 2, 1]})
df.iloc[-1]['c'] = 42 # SettingWithCopyWarning: ...
```

It seems that pandas (at least `v0.23.4`) handles mixed-type and single-type dataframes differently when it comes to chain assignments [[3]](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9c814fd38f6ff73c53f286fdc71ca9512b81aef/pandas/core/generic.py#L3159)

> ```
> def _check_is_chained_assignment_possible(self):
>     """
>     Check if we are a view, have a cacher, and are of mixed type.
>     If so, then force a setitem_copy check.
>     Should be called just near setting a value
>     Will return a boolean if it we are a view and are cached, but a
>     single-dtype meaning that the cacher should be updated following
>     setting.
>     """
>     if self._is_view and self._is_cached:
>         ref = self._get_cacher()
>         if ref is not None and ref._is_mixed_type:
>             self._check_setitem_copy(stacklevel=4, t='referant',
>                                      force=True)
>         return True
>     elif self._is_copy:
>         self._check_setitem_copy(stacklevel=4, t='referant')
>     return False
> ```

which appears really odd to me although I'm not sure if it's not expected.

However, there's an old [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9767) with a similar behavour.

---

**UPDATE**

According to the [developers](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24315) the above behaviour is expected.

Answer (score 9):

Don't focus on the warning. The warning is just an indication, sometimes it doesn't even come up [when you expect it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788871/pandas-loc-indexing-with-inplace-fillna). Sometimes you will notice it [occurs inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807453/9209546). Instead, just avoid [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) or generally working with what could be a copy.

You wish to index by **row integer location** and **column label**. That's an unnatural mix, given Pandas has functionality to index by integer positions or labels, *but not both simultaneously*.

In this case, you can use use **integer positional indexing** for both rows and columns via a single [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) call:

```
df.iat[-1, df.columns.get_loc('C')] = 3
```

Or, if your index labels are *guaranteed* to be unique, you can use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
df.at[df.index[-1], 'C'] = 3
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer. I was stuck for few hours for something that seems has no problem but still getting warning sometimes and sometimes not: 

`df.loc['filename', 'prediction score'] = 0.3`

Comment: I found it very interesting that an output CSV file I created with no chaining contained problem lines. Almost all iat usage worked but it does not seem to be side effect free. It broke some lines. If I used iloc with chaining I get perfect results.

Answer (score 7):

So it's pretty hard to answer this without context around your problem operation, but [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) covers this pretty well.

```
>>> df[['C']].iloc[0] = 2 # This is a problem
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Basically it boils down to - don't chain together indexing operations if you can just use a single operation to do it.

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'C'] = 2 # This is ok
```

The warning you're getting is because you've failed to set a value in the original dataframe that you're presumably trying to modify - instead, you've copied it and set something into the copy (usually when this happens to me I don't even have a reference to the copy and it just gets garbage collected, so the warning is pretty helpful)